# problems with Apache on Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, apache-http-server

I kind of screwed up the Apache "stuff" on my Mac. Usually when I visit `http://localhost/`, I would see the "It Works!" but now it just lists the directory and files inside `/Library/WebServer/Documents`.

When I try to stop/start/restart the server with `sudo apachectl stop`, I get:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 68 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_disk_cache.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_disk_cache.so, 10): Symbol not found: _apr_file_info_get$INODE64\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_disk_cache.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_disk_cache.so
```

I don't want to do the MacPorts install, I tried it earlier but... I just want to do it via source code with the usual ./configure, make, make install.

Any ideas on how to get this working? Is there a way to totally remove Apache and then reinstall a fresh version?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the offending line in your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up backing up all of my files, erasing and re-installing Snow Leopard, and Apache was back to normal.